# How to use Prisma to generate database tables in Docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

## Goal

I'm trying to make a minimal **Express** app. It has a single endpoint `/users` that either GETs all users in a **Postgres database**, or POSTs a new user. I'm trying to use **Prisma** as an ORM and run everything with **docker-compose**.

I'm attempting to build this minimal example specifically with the goal of understanding how to use Prisma with docker-compose.

## Problem

Ultimately I want a user to be able to simply run `docker-compose up` and have everything working. That means that I'm assuming that no existing database volume exists, so, upon building the images, Docker needs to

1. **Create a `users` database** in the Postgres container (? I'm not sure if this is created by default as defined in the connection URL)
2. **Create a `users` table** within that database, which I'm hoping to do with `npx prisma db push` so that the `schema.prisma` file is used

**I'm wondering what the "proper" way to do this is?** I'm fairly new to Prisma and Docker beyond basic examples, so any insight or advice is greatly appreciated!

Additionally, insight as to **where/how to inject the `DATABASE_URL`** environment variable would be great. It seems Prisma relies on a `.env` file, but can this equivalently be injected in the `docker-compose.yml` as I've done?

I've included all relevant code below, thank you again!

## `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "express_prisma_postgres_compose",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.12.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "prisma": "^4.12.0"
  }
}
```

## `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

# use ci instead?
RUN npm install

# Add prisma schema
COPY ./prisma/schema.prisma ./prisma/schema.prisma

# NOTE: Have to copy .env file so that prisma can use it?
# COPY .env ./

# Generate Prisma client
RUN npx prisma generate

# Push changes to DB
RUN npx prisma db push

# Run separately bc different layer. Makes rebuilding image faster.
COPY . .

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

## `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRED_DB=users
    # We don't have to expose this port because the containers communicate inside the docker network
    #ports:
    #  - '5432:5432'
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  server:
    build:
      # Build image from the specified dockerfile in the specified folder.
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      #env_file: .env
      - DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users"

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

## `schema.prisma`

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model users {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  username String? @db.VarChar(50)
}
```

## `.env`

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users"
```

## `index.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create a new Prisma client instance
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// Endpoint for retrieving all users from the database
app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await prisma.users.findMany();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
});

// Endpoint for adding a new user to the database
app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = req.body;
    const { username } = newUser;
    const user = await prisma.users.create({
      data: {
        username,
      },
    });
    res.status(201).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: I know this post is almost a year old but did you ever solve this issue? I'm trying to do something similar and I've been banging my head against a wall for 2 days at this point trying to get things working

Answer (score 0):

In your server app `Dockerfile`, instead of running `CMD ["node" "index.js"]`, you can run a custom script:

```
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

In your server app `package.json` you can create such script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "yarn db:sync && node index.js",
  "db:sync": "prisma db push"
}
```

Replace `yarn` with your favorite tool (e.g. npm).

As for environment variables, it seems you already figured it out, instead of using `.env` file you can just inject them via docker-compose yaml.

This works for me, though I only use it for local dev or demo purposes.